# Random variable $(X, Y)$ with unknown pdf is the result of the random experiment. How to estimate $E[Y |X =E(x)]$ without fixing X = E[X]?

Tags: probability

I can generate random discrete 2-d variable $(X, Y)$. However, I don't have their joint pdf. Is there a way to find $E[Y | X = E[X]]$? I used a sampling method to generate two combinatorial objects (basically I have a program that does it). But, I'm generally curious if it is possible to use any experiments to estimate $E[Y | X = E[X]]$.

For example one could estimate $E[X]$ by taking the average value of $X$. Averaging point-by-point gives $(E[x], E[Y])$. Perhaps there is an another averaging method.

Also, the point $(E[X], E[Y | X = E[X]])$ seems to coincide with the peak of my distribution? Could this help?

Comment: If you don't have the joint pdf, then what *do* you have?

Comment: Basically, I can make experiments to get (X, Y) according to the distribution I don't know yet. I've updated the question, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $E(x)$ as opposed to $E[X]$?

Comment: You can't "find" the mean of $X$ by averaging sampled values of it; you can *estimate* the mean that way. Are you looking to *estimate* the value of $E[Y\mid X=E[X]]$ given values of $(X,Y)$ under some assumption about its distribution?

Comment: E(x) is a typo. I mean E[X] everywhere.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean estimate. I could of course fix $X = E[X]$, and average $Y$ to estimate $E[Y | X = X]$, but it wouldn't help me find the formula. 

Basically, my question is the there a process like "averaging", that I could use to derive a formula.